# How to make human image with background-color in html and css3

Tags: html, css

I have been created web page using html5, css3 and jQuery.

Now I just confused with creating human image with background-color.

May I know, is possible to create by using `html5,css3`?

```
<img src="Saina_hybd.png" style="background-color:red;" />
```

I need like this, http://s3.postimg.org/vol07gleb/Untitled_2.png

Can anyone help me to do this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: So u want to color the person in red?

Comment: Like Bill gates face is yellow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not directly add background color property to image. You just create a div before the image and apply background color property to div and just reduce the opacity of the image.

```css
.image_box {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}
.image_box img {
  float: left;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="image_box">
    <img src="http://www.paritybars.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/man-ok.png" alt="ok">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks @jalak modi: .. i need a background as full width.. on the web page.. but you did bg color for only image right?

Comment: so i added width for image_box selector ,, and i need to place the image on the right side and added text like my posted image. can you help me @jalak?

Comment: yes, I have also apply bg-color to both div and image but you should only apply to the div. because image can't directly take bg-color so we have to reduce the opacity of the image.

Comment: here is my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/0fmLw8rg/ . how to add text on left side of my image

Comment: yes you should add text on left side of the left side of the image and apply property float:left and color:#000; so they can not take opacity like image.you have to change any color of that text...:)

Comment: here is my image, http://s30.postimg.org/6vlhuvmxt/saina.jpg .. i need to clear background, i need only image.. like you used in your answer, can you please help

Comment: ok so you can cut the image in photoshop and then you can use that perticular image.so m i right you want only a sayina nehwal pic na?

Comment: just post in postimage.org.. and send me a link.. thanks

Comment: what? what do you mean.

Comment: i am asking.. how to cut the image?